# Execute program in current shell within shell script

Tags: shell, ssh, awk, scripting, zsh

I made a little shell script, that parses the .ssh config and allows me to pick an entry with fzf, and then connects to that host:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o nounset -o errexit -o pipefail

list_remote_hosts()
{
    choice="$(cat $HOME/.ssh/config | awk -v RS= -v FS=\\n -v IGNORECASE=1 '
        {
            ip = ""
            alias = ""
            id_file = ""
            username = ""
            port = ""

            for (j = 1; j <= NF; ++j) {
                split($j, tmp, " ")
                if (tmp[1] == "Host") { alias = tmp[2] }
                if (tmp[1] == "Hostname") { ip = tmp[2] }
                if (tmp[1] == "IdentityFile") { id_file = tmp[2] }
                if (tmp[1] == "User") { username = tmp[2] }
                if (tmp[1] == "Port") { port = tmp[2] }
            }

            if (ip || alias && alias != "*") {
                if (port == "")
                {
                    port = "22"
                }
                print "ssh " username "@" ip " -i " id_file " -p " port
            }
        }
    ' | fzf)"

    "$($choice)"
}

list_remote_hosts
```

That works, but I am having problems giving ownership to the current shell.
When connected, the script freezes (because ssh is started in a subshell I imagine).
Once I type e.g. exit, and the ssh command terminates, I can see the output.

I want to automatically give ownership to the current shell when the script is run, so that I get the same behavior like running the ssh command from within my terminal.

I tried all sorts of things like appending `&& zsh` or using `eval` or `exec`, but none of these worked.
How can I do this?

Comment: Note that `ssh **<TAB>` with the default keybindings of fzf will already invoke fzf to select the host to connect to (https://github.com/junegunn/fzf#host-names).

Comment: `cat file | awk '...'` is functionally identical to `awk '...' file`, except the shorter version is better code. `cat file` is usually unnecessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `"$($choice)"` to simply `$choice` (no quotes) -- that should expand the awk output into words and spawn the ssh command from the current process

---

This looks like it might be a problem

```bsh
if (ip || alias && alias != "*") {
    if (port == "") port = "22"
    print "ssh " username "@" ip " -i " id_file " -p " port
}
```

What happens if `ip` is empty but `alias` is not? You'll enter the block, but you don't use the alias variable anywhere. You might want

```c
if (!ip) { ip = alias }
if (ip && ip != "*") { ...
```

---

This might work as an alternative way to structure the function. Untested:

```bsh
remote_host_connect() {
    awk '...' $HOME/.ssh/config \
    | fzf \
    | sh </dev/tty >/dev/tty 2>&1
}
```

---

This works for me as a standalone script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
eval "$(
    awk -v RS= -F'[[:space:]]+' '{
        for (i=1; i<NF; i+=2)
            data[$i]=$(i+1)
        ip = (data["HostName"] ? data["HostName"] : data["Host"])
        if (ip && ip != "*")
            printf "ssh %s@%s %s %s\n",
                (data["User"] ? data["User"] : ENVIRON["LOGNAME"]),
                ip,
                (data["IdentityFile"] ? "-i " data["IdentityFile"] : ""),
                "-p " (data["Port"] ? data["Port"] : 22)
    }' ~/.ssh/config \
    | fzf
)"
```

Comment: That doesn't do anything. I don't get any output. It just hangs while waiting for input. I know my input is being sent via ssh, because if I type exit, it prints "Connection to ... closed". But I dont get the interactive shell.

Comment: maybe you need `ssh -t`

Comment: Nope, same problem remains with the `-t` flag. I just saw your edit. Will try and report back.

Comment: I tried the suggestion from your last edit, but the problem still remains. When executing the script, I am prompted: `zsh: suspended (tty output)  /home/user/.scripts/script.sh`

Comment: It would probably be better to make it a zsh function (that executes in your current, interactive zsh session) instead of a bash script that runs in a separate process.

Comment: The reason I'd prefer a bash script, is because of its portability. I can just transfer the script to any machine and it works, without needing to setup my zsh environment there. Is it not possible to just execute the process in the current shell, rather than spawning a new one? Maybe I fail to understand the problem..

Comment: Assuming the "ssh" in the script is the problem, try changing "ssh" to "ssh -f".